# Mysql compare 2 values to 2 columns from vb6 to database using stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb6, sql-insert

I have a `products` table in my database with columns/fields:

- ProductID
- Productname
- description
- supplier
- purchasedate
- Quantity

Now, what I want to achieve is this:

- Every time I want to add new values in my `products` table, the "productname" and "supplier" values of new input will compare all the values existing in `products` table.

Scenarios:

- If NEW productname and supplier values are already existing in `products` table, the quantity of new value will add to the quantity of existing values
- ELSE if it is not existing, then add the NEW values to the `products` table.

Heres the tried code but it's not working:

```
Delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE `wew`(pid int,pname varchar(50),pdesc varchar(50),psupp varchar(50),pdate date,pquant int)
begin
declare lloyd char default null;
select productname from products where productname=pname LIMIT 1 into lloyd for update;
if(lloyd) then
update products set quantityleft=quantityleft+pquant where productname=pname;
else
insert into products (productid,productname,proddescription,supplier,lastpurchasedate,quantityleft) values(pid,pname,pdesc,psupp,pdate,pquant);
end if;
end;
//
```

Can you help with this one? Really confused with this.

DESC PRODUCT:

```
SQL result

Host: localhost
Database: prodpurchase
Generation Time: Mar 24, 2013 at 03:52 PM
Generated by: phpMyAdmin 3.2.4 / MySQL 5.1.41
SQL query: Desc Products; 
Rows: 7

Field             Type            Null      Key      Default    Extra
ProdID            int(5)          NO        PRI       NULL  auto_increment
ProdName          varchar(50)      NO       UNI       NULL   
ProdSupplier      varchar(250)     NO       UNI       NULL   
ProdDescription   varchar(250)     NO        NULL    
ProdDate          date             NO        NULL    
ProdPrice         double            NO       0   
ProdQuantity      int(50)        NO      NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of MySQL's **[INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)**

First, you need to add a `UNIQUE` constraint ot columns: `productname` and `supplier`:

```
ALTER TABLE products ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (productname, supplier)
```

Once you have executed that,

```
INSERT INTO products (productid, productname, proddescription, supplier, lastpurchasedate, quantityleft)
VALUES (pid, pname, pdesc, psupp, pdate, pquant)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantityleft = quantityleft + pquant;
```

Comment: You know what man, YOU ARE REALLY BRILLIANT!Almost all my database projects were accomplished successfully because of you. THANKS!

Comment: It makes me proud even more being a Filipino. Many thanks. God Bless you and you family.

Comment: Hey man, I have errors with the code. Whenever i have same name with supplier, it says duplicate. I want to achieve, ONE PRODUCT MAY HAVE MANY SUPPLIIERS AND ONE SUPPLIER MAY HAVE MANY PRODUCTS. Something like that. Hope I make myself clear to you.

Comment: post the result of this statement along with your question: `DESC product`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. What do you mean ?

Comment: i need to know the structure of your table. by executing `DESC product` it will give you he schema of the table `product`

Comment: i was wondering why it throws an exception. I was anticipating that it won;t because of this line: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quantityleft = quantityleft + pquant`

Comment: What I meant when I said prodname and prodsupplier was it should be both prodname and supplier that should not be existing in a row. If any is not satisfied with that then add the new value to tha table, if it satifies thats the only way the prodquantity will be updated. Thanks.

Comment: i think your schema design is wrong. Follow this steps. Remove the `UNIQUE` keys in your table, excpet for the primary key. After that, execute this one `ALTER TABLE products ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (productname, supplier)` it will enforce uniqueness on both columns not per column.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26814/discussion-between-j-w-and-scarface23)